# Cannot login anywhere on domain: Profile cannot be loaded

Tags: active-directory, windows-7

I'm having this issue with one of our users. This is a roaming profile, and I've tried logging in on a few machines, but we're still getting the same error.

I did go through cleaning folders and the registry / SID, but that didn't seem to change anything, even when trying to log in on a new machine.

Nothing has been changed except the fact the user was logged in when the machine crashed, and the next time they tried, the error appeared.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the profile and having the user login?

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do to remove someones profile is not cleaning the actual folder but creating a .%username%.old folder under users and moving the entire user folder that is located in c:\users\ directory there, and also cleaning out the sid in registry which you already did